# Store multiple files in single document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to use NSDocument to store the data of my application. And I want the user to able to embed images into the documents. In order to not store the path to the embedded image in my document I want to embed their content.

I have seen that for instance Keynote is storing all the images in its document. How can I do similar things in my class that extends NSDocument? When I overwrite the `readFromData` and `dataOfType` methods I have to deal with `NSData` which won't allow me such things. Do I have to override the `fromUrl` stuff to do so?
Or will I have to deal with all the low level stuff that NSDocument does for me on my own and create a `NSFilePresenter` implementation on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your document a File Wrapper, so in fact it becomes a directory but the Finder will show it as a single entity. The methods to use are in NSDocument:

- fileWrapperOfType:error:
- readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:

Use these instead of readFromData and dataOfType. You'll need to read up on file wrappers (NSFileWrapper) also.

I have read some recommendations against using file wrappers. I think I read that some compression programs have trouble correctly archiving and expanding them, eg. for sending via email. I don't think it was an apple recommendation though, and sounds more like a shortcoming of the archiving program to me.